# Nomination suspension notification modal window z-index issue

Tags: bug, design, user-interface, election, account-suspension

I was suspended within the last year and when I tried opening the [nomination](https://stackoverflow.com/election?tab=nomination) window, I get this `z-index` messed up view.

[image: preview]

The fix is simple. Currently the `z-index` of the `.lightbox` is `8950`. And our notification modal (`.message.message-takeover`) has it as `1001 !important`, both in [`all.css`](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/all.css?v=e5c0763b44a0). Either we need to override the `!important` with the right value of greater than `8950` or we need to get rid of the `!important`.

```css
.message.message-takeover {
  position: absolute;
  width: 480px;
  top: 260px;
  left: calc(50% - 240px);
  z-index: 1001 !important;               /* Change this to 8951? */
}
```

A possible solution would be:

```css
.message.message-takeover {
  position: absolute;
  width: 480px;
  top: 260px;
  left: calc(50% - 240px);
  z-index: 8955 !important;               /* Change this to 8955 */
}
```

Comment: [cross-site dupe](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/352431/559745)

Comment: Ouch... I tried searching @Floern but didn't get it...

Comment: @Floern Looks like there wasn't much traffic to that question out there. I am planning to wait if someone from the team looks at this, (better visibility, right?) If not, I'll delete this question soon. What say?

Comment: Keep it for the moment. I've no idea how they handle (dupe) bug reports backstage.

Comment: @Floern Thanks mate... `:)`

Comment: MSE/MSO dupes are fine as far as I can tell.